# Updating SharePoint User Profile Picture

Tags: user-profile, sharepoint-on-prem, sql-server, ms-flow, automation

I have a SP 2013 Production on premise environment where the users are not allowed to update their User profile pictures.

User pictures are updated in a different application and image files are stored in a network drive. Using Powershell Scripts, the path to the pictures are updated in SharePoint user profiles.

Right now the process to update SharePoint user profile pic is as follows:

1. A Powershell script exports the Login names of the users in SharePoint user profile to a CSV file
2. A SQL query retrieves the Login names and profile picture path of the respective user from the SQL DB of the other application. The output is then pasted to a CSV file.
3. CSV files from Step 1 and Step 2 are compared using MS Access DB and the output is copied to another CSV file.
4. CSV file from step 3 is provided as input to a Powershell script which updates the image location in SharePoint user profile. Then an incremental profile sync is run manually.

I have to automate this process to run automatically once a week. I need directions/suggestions on how to achieve this? May be a MS flow solution or any custom code?

Comment: You should be able to combine all the steps into one big script and run that as a scheduled task by an account with access to both SharePoint and the db where you have the information about images and login names. You can execute SQL-cmdlts through PowerShell and then loop through both CSV's and compare them for changes/if they exists, generate an array and use that to update UPS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682703/connect-to-sql-server-database-from-powershell